# How to query HBASE in wso2 DSS

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

Can we query HBASE in wso2 DSS? As I have not found anything related to querying of HBASE in wso2 DSS documentation.

But in documentation they have written as any database with a JDBC driver. So, is it possible in wso2 DSS?